# Excel Power Query: Merge Join on Date Range

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to do something very similar to your article here, but I cannot get it to work.

I have 2 tables:  "XYZ Charges - PQ" and "Land Orders".

"XYZ Charges - PQ" includes 3 columns: "Land Account No.", "STDATE", and "STDATE - 7".
"Land Orders" includes 2 columns: "Acct No." and "Order Date".

I need to merge/join "XYZ Charges - PQ" and "Land Orders" together.  "Land Account No." need to match "Acct No." exactly, but "Order Date" needs to be between "STDATE" and "STDATE - 7".

In the Power Query Editor, I tried to add a custom column with the following:
`= Table.AddColumn(#"XYZ Charges - PQ", "Table.SelectRows()", (X)=> Table.SelectRows(#"Land Orders - Grouped", (L)=> L[#"Account No."]=X[#"Harland Account No."] and X[PSTDATE] >= L[#"Invoice Date"] and X[PSTDATE] <= L[#"Invoice Date"]))`

But I either get null results or received this error:
*Expression.Error: There is an unknown identifier. Did you use the [field] shorthand for a _[field] outside of an 'each' expression?*

What am I missing?

Thank you,
Cin

Answer (score 1):

The formula you want is

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"XYZ Charges - PQ",(x) => [Order Date] >= x[#"STDATE - 7"] and [Order Date] <=x[#"STDATE"] and [#"Acct No."]=x[#"Land Account No."])
```

or in another format

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"ACH Charges - PQ", "Custom", each Table.SelectRows(#"XYZ Charges - PQ",(x) => [Order Date] >= x[#"STDATE - 7"] and [Order Date] <=x[#"STDATE"] and [#"Acct No."]=x[#"Land Account No."]))
```

full sample code for Land Orders

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceTableLandOrders"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Acct No.", type text}, {"Order Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Table.SelectRows(#"XYZ Charges - PQ",(x) => [Order Date] >= x[#"STDATE - 7"] and [Order Date] <=x[#"STDATE"] and [#"Acct No."]=x[#"Land Account No."]))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

to attempt to speed this up, try using a Table.Buffer() around the #"XYZ Charges - PQ"  step taking place before this step.

```
#"XYZ Charges - PQ" = Table.Buffer(..existing code...) ,
```

Comment: Thank you, @horseride.  I was able to use the code to create something that worked.  However, now I am running into performance issues. It did not take too much time to join the tables and it did not take too much time to expand the columns in the PQ editor.  But it took all night and morning to load only 50% of the data back to Excel.  Any ideas?

Comment: It’s a terrible method because you are doing a full search of two tables for every row. How many rows are in the xyz table ? It may be better to expand that and just do a straight match

Comment: XYZ has 56,441 rows.  The other table has 41,631 rows.

Comment: What do you mean by straight match?  Is it with in Power Query?

Comment: Doesnt seem like it should take that long for only 50,000 records

Comment: So this might be a hardware or connectivity issue?  I have to do this on a VPN computer.

Comment: Find the step where you create #"XYZ Charges - PQ" before this formula and surround the existing code with Table.Buffer(), similar to #"XYZ Charges - PQ" = Table.Buffer (Table.AddColumns(....)),